# Security for SharePoint Document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepointdocumentlibrary

We have SharePoint integration with D365
I am having a requirement to isolate SharePoint documents between different Model driven apps in Power platform. Ex: B2B App users should able to see Documents related to B2B Opportunities. Currently Both B2C and B2B opportunity documents saved on Opportunity folder. Users should not able to browse documents belong to other app. What is the best way to achieve this ?

Move documents between different folders